Apply function to a groupby and rolling group
Given a pandas dataframe, group it by 3 levels and apply a function which takes two columns as arguments on a rolling basis:
Code to create the data frame:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_index = pd.DataFrame({
    'classes': ['A']*3*3 +  ['B']*3*3 +['C']*3*3,
    'names': ['Alex']*3 + ['Alan']*3 + ['Ash']*3 + ['Bart']*3 + ['Blake']*3 + ['Beth']*3 + ['Charlie']*3 + ['Cristine']*3 + ['Cameron']*3,
    'numbers': [0, 1, 2] * 9
})

df_values = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(), index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2024-01-01'), columns=['net', 'gross']).rename_axis('date').reset_index(drop=False)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df_index)):
    _df = df_values.copy()
    _df['classes'] = df_index.iloc[i]['classes']
    _df['names'] = df_index.iloc[i]['names']
    _df['numbers'] = df_index.iloc[i]['numbers']
    df = pd.concat((df, _df), axis=0)

df.set_index(['classes','names','numbers','date'], inplace=True)

Some function:
def fun(net, gross):
    return net.mean() / gross.std()

The following does not work. I am looking to groupby, and apply "fun()" in a rolling basis:
df.groupby(['classes', 'names', 'numbers']).rolling(window=500).apply(
    lambda x: fun(net=x['net'], gross=x['gross'])  
)

Thanks.
PS: the real fun() is much complex than the one here so I cannot calculate ".mean()" and ".std()" directly to the groupby.

rolling.apply operates per column, so it isn't directly possible to use multiple columns.

rolling.apply operates per column, so it isn't directly possible to use multiple columns.
Instead you could slice one column and use a side effect by slicing the original DataFrame based on the indices of the window:
(df.groupby(['classes', 'names', 'numbers']).rolling(window=500)['net']
   .apply(lambda x: fun(net=df.loc[x.index, 'net'],
                        gross=df.loc[x.index, 'gross']))
)

But be aware that the operation might be very slow!

Replacing "net=df.loc[x.index, 'net']" by "net=x" would work as well and faster right?

@AlexSB you could pass x to the function fun(x) but you'd have to slice the DataFrame in the function then. Just passing (net=x, gross=x) wouldn't work.

not both. only the net=x. Since the rolling and apply is done based on ['net'] column already?

Unless I misunderstood what you meant, no you can't pass x unless you modify the function to perform the dataframe slicing inside it.

As commented, .groupby().rolling().apply() works on the columns, so you don't have access to other columns in groupby. You can try unstack the group indexes and rolling on the wide dataframe:
wide_df = df.unstack(['classes','names','numbers'])

window = 5
fun(wide_df['net'].dropna().rolling(window).mean(),
    wide_df['gross'].dropna().rolling(window).std())

